# Difference between Promise.resolve() and Promise(resolve => resolve())

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I found some code snippet that has the same behavior, But the different syntax of resolving a promise from a function :

```
return new Promise(resolve => resolve(fruits[name]))
```

and

```
return Promise.resolve(fruits[name])
```

What is the difference between both?

Comment: Second one is shorter.

Comment: second one returns a promise resolved with a value provided as input of the `.resolve` method. First one accepts a callback which can do any operations inside, and then `reject` or `resolve` depending on those operations

Comment: Notice that `Promise.resolve` will return the argument if it already is a promise - although this should never matter in practice, it's a subtle difference.

Comment: @quirimmo Thanks. I got the point.